# onSensorChanged Azimut Value Jumps

Tags: android, android-activity, compass-geolocation

I am new to Android, so I believe I made a mistake somewhere and is unable to fix it. I have a Main Activity, lets call it a Main menu. From this I start other activities by pressing the appropriate button to launch the activity I want. The problem is I use the onSensorchanged() in one of the launched activities. If the application is started the first time, the launched activity values behave as expected, but if I close the activity (in other words now I am back in the main menu) and a launch the activity again the values read from the onSensorchanged() jumps. Correct values are combined with wrong values. I use intents to launch the second activity and think that the problem is with this.

The main menu code:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity{

Button gps_btn,lineFollow_btn,man_control_btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    addListenerOnButton();
    Debug.startMethodTracing("Navigation Trace");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() 
{


    super.onPause();
    Debug.stopMethodTracing();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() 
{

    final Context context = this;

    gps_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GPS_btn);

    gps_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AutoControl.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

    lineFollow_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.line_follower_btn);

    lineFollow_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, CamDemoActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);   

        }

    });

    man_control_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.man_ctrl_btn);

    man_control_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, ManualAct_PLC.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);   

        }

    });

}
```

The code for the OnSensorChanged:

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        gravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        geoMagnetic = event.values;
    if (gravity != null && geoMagnetic != null) 
    {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity,geoMagnetic);

        if (success) 
        {
            /* Orientation has azimuth, pitch and roll */
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            float azimut = orientation[0];
            updateSensorInfoView(azimut);           
            steerRobot(azimut);
            System.out.println("Raw Sensor value:"  + Double.toString(Math.toDegrees(azimut)));
            System.out.println("Degree Sensor value:"  + calculations.compassDegString(azimut));
        }
    }

}
```

Viewing the values logged, once the AutoControl Activity is launched again my sensor data is unexpected:

```
    01-04 17:52:34.925: I/System.out(31387): Calculatebearing value:2.168326647225342
    01-04 17:52:34.925: I/System.out(31387): Raw Sensor value:-116.11590698474976
    01-04 17:52:34.925: I/System.out(31387): Degree Sensor value:244.0
    01-04 17:52:34.955: I/System.out(31387): Calculatebearing value:173.96307878454928
    01-04 17:52:34.955: I/System.out(31387): Raw Sensor value:72.0893408779263
    01-04 17:52:34.955: I/System.out(31387): Degree Sensor value:72.0
    01-04 17:52:35.065: I/System.out(31387): Calculatebearing value:108.5784565015826
    01-04 17:52:35.065: I/System.out(31387): Raw Sensor value:137.473963160893
    01-04 17:52:35.070: I/System.out(31387): Degree Sensor value:137.0
```

Notice the degree sensor value has jumped considerably in short time. I have an arrow that is drawn on the screen based on the calculated bearing angle, which jumps around like crazy once the activity is loaded the second time.

I am suspecting that a second instance is created of this activity, but used the android:launchMode="singleInstance" tag in the Manifest file to try and prevent this.

I have anyone else experienced such a problem? I dont seem to find similar problems on the net.

Answer (score 0):

After moving the problem activity into its own application, I still experienced the same problem. Eliminating the concern that multiple instances of the same activity is running.

After reading this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/UNMaDEUcXb0

I resolved the problem by changing my code OnSensorchanged method. There seems to be a problem with the pointer after multiple runs, so its better to use a clone of the senor values object changing:

changing

case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    mag = event.values;

to

case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    mag = event.values.clone();